# Adding screenshot functionality to a firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, screenshot

Is there a cross-platform approach to taking screenshots from a firefox extension?

Ideally I'd like to be able to take a screenshot of a dom element (irrespective of whether it's visible on the page or not), something like:

var screenshot = screenshot(document.getElementById('example');

Any pointers or suggestions would be nice, searching https://developer.mozilla.org/ only yields screenshots they've used in various guides.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After examining the code of several extensions. I took the following approach (to take a snapshot of a particular dom element). This can be used in a Firefox extension to take screenshots of the whole page, to take screenshots of the browser window and to take screenshots of a particular dom element (and all of its child nodes):

1. Add canvas to xul.
2. Find dimensions and top-left co-ordinates of element.
3. Copy portion of window to canvas.
4. Convert canvas to base64 PNG file.

> ```
> function getElementScreenshot(elm) {
>     var x = findPosX(elm);
>     var y = findPosY(elm);
>     var width = elm.clientWidth;
>     var height = elm.clientHeight;
>     var cnvs = document.getElementById("aCanvas");
>     cnvs.width = width;
>     cnvs.height = height;
>     var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
>     // To take a snapshot of entire window
>     // ctx.drawWindow(mainWindow.content, 0, 0, mainWindow.innerWidth, mainWindow.innerHeight, "rgb(255,255,255)");
>     ctx.drawWindow(mainWindow.content, x, y, width, height, "rgb(255,255,255)");
>     return(cnvs.toDataURL());
> }
> ```

---

To find top left coordinate of an element

```
function findPosX(obj) {
    var curleft = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        while (1) {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            if (!obj.offsetParent) {
                break;
            }
            obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    } else if (obj.x) {
        curleft += obj.x;
    }
    return curleft;
}

function findPosY(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        while (1) {
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
            if (!obj.offsetParent) {
                break;
            }
            obj = obj.offsetParent;
        }
    } else if (obj.y) {
        curtop += obj.y;
    }
    return curtop;
}
```

---

To get access to browser.xul from sidebar

```
var mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                       .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
                       .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                       .rootTreeItem
                       .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                       .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

mainWindow.gBrowser.addTab(...);
```

Comment: This solution works great, although on youtube when flash video is playing, if you take SS, it shows black box instead of video capture. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: @Ivan: Were you able to upload this as an add-on somewhere? I could use that. Apparently even today there's no add-on which allows it directly.

Answer (score 2):

Download one of the many Firefox screen capture extensions, and look at their code to see how they do it. Eg [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146/), [Fireshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5648/), or [Page Saver](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10367/)

Comment: Thanks, I'd looked at a couple and found Page Saver the easiest one to follow and understand.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it would be something like this:

1. Copy the DOM element in question to a separate iframe or browser (which is not visible to the user)
2. Paint the window of that iframe onto an html canvas using drawWindow(). Check out the source of the Tab Preview addon to see how this is done.

Comment: Looking at the Tab Preview addon now. Thanks